# Call form request from controller based on request input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a controller that accepts input. This input is parsed by a request validation (POSRequest). If the request validation succeeded, the request is then passed into the controller. Standard laravel stuff.
I have to typehint in the controller POSRequest $requests in order to fire the request validation, how can I call other requests based on the input provided in POSRequest $request?
**Here is some code to clear things up a bit**:
`public function process(POSRequest $request){ ... }`
All of my requests come to **process** function and based on input of $requests i need to call other functions:
`private function StartRequest(POSStartRequest $request) { ... }`
`private function CheckRequest(POSCheckRequest $request) { ... }`
How can i call these frunctions from within the controller from within the process function and convert POSRequest to either one of other requests?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually create validators in controller method

```
public function process(Request $request) {
        $rulesFirstRequest = ['field1' => 'required', 'field2' => 'required'];
        $rulesSecondRequest = ['field12' => 'required', 'field22' => 'required'];

        $validator1 = Validator::make($request->all(), $rulesFirstRequest);
        $validator2 = Validator::make($request->all(), $rulesSecondRequest);

        if ($validator1->fails()) {
            //do your stuff
            if ($validator2->fails()) {
                //do your stuff    
            }
        }
        // next stuff
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!
I know I can do that, the problem with doing it this way, is that all of my logic lies in one file, and the controller will be very big because of it. I would really  love for it to be in seperate Request

Comment: You can declare specific class that handles on validation logic manually

Comment: Care to give example?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different form request classes and then use an if statement to check the validation class you want to call. Call them by doing this in the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613372/10271408