# How to Create an Form Request Manually in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, validation

I am using Following Form Request array

```
class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the data for validation.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $check_percentance = false;
        if($this->discount){
            $check_percentance = Str::substrCount($this->discount,'%');
        }
        $discount_price = Str::replace('%', '%', $this->discount);
        if($this->quantity && $this->unit_cost){
            $total = $this->quantity * $this->unit_cost;
        }
        $this->merge([
            'discount_percent' => $check_percentance ? true:false,
            'discount'=> (float) $discount_price,
            'total_cost' => (float) ($total ?? $this->total_cost)
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'sku' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'quantity' => 'required|numeric',
            'unit_cost'=>'required|numeric',
        ];
        return $rules;
    }


    /**
     * Handle a passed validation attempt.
     */
    protected function passedValidation(): void
    {
        // calculate Discount price value
        $total_discount_amount = 0;
        
        $this->merge(['total_discount_amount'=> $total_discount_amount]);
    }
}
```

I Would like to create a request manually like below

```
$productRequest = new ProductRequest($product);  // $proudts is an php array
```

When I print `$productRequest` I amt not getting validated and returned array doesn't having merged data which was created in `passedValidation()` and `prepareForValidation()` function,

Can any one help me to sort out this?

I have tried multiple way and googling about this But no solutions

Comment: Can I asked what is the output of `$productRequest` when you print it ?

Answer (score 0):

The `prepareForValidation()` method is called by the `validResolved()` method which you cannot work without a complete request.

You can change `prepareForValidation()` override to public and call it from your class.

```
 /**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'string']
    ];
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
public function passedValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge(['age' => 99]);
}


##### Test

$request = new TestRequest(['name' => 'test']);
$request->passedValidation();
dump($request->all());
//  array:2 [▼
//    "name" => "test"
//    "age" => 99
//  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller pass the request as an argument then call the validation class you created

```
class sampleController extends Controller {
   public function test(Request $request)
   {
     $request->validate((new ProductRequest())->rules());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form request can be resolved manually *through* the app container:

```
$productRequest = app('App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest');
```

I needed it to utilize rules(), messages() and failedValidation() methods of the form request. The line above has been used in Controller and if validation failed, no more code has been executed from it.

> You should type hint it as parameter in your function.

In my case the controller handled many different FormRequests and deciding which one, was based on form's POST fields - not something to be handled in routing.